# Formula to return column header if there is data in the column

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I need a formula to return column header if there is data in the column, any data.
But I also need to return the second, third, fourth header with data too

In column A row 2, I have =IF(M8<>"",$M$1,IF(N8<>"",$N$1,IF(O8<>"",$O$1,IF(P8<>"",$P$1,IF(Q8<>"",$Q$1,IF(R8<>"",$R$1,IF(S8<>"",$S$1,IF(T8<>"",$T$1,""))))))))

This returns the row 1 header for the first instance of data in row 2 columns M thru T
But in B2, I need the second header with data in the column.

I need the results in yellow (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th) from the array to it's left

```
 1St match   2nd        3rd         4th            Column M    Column N    Column O    Column P    Column Q    Column R    Column S    Column T
Column M    Column O    Colum R                      Data                  data2                               Data3        
Coulmn N    Column O    Column Q    Column T                    Data        Data2                   data3                               data4
```

Would use match/index but can't increment it to the second or 3rd match
Thanks

Comment: If this is a relatively small dataset and you only need it to do this once, you might be able to get away with just Paste Transpose and clever filtering and sorting.  How many rows and columns are there?

Comment: Also, what kind of data is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this "array formula" in A2 confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and copied across

`=IFERROR(INDEX($M$1:$T$1,SMALL(IF($M8:$T8<>"",COLUMN($M8:$T8)-COLUMN($M8)+1),COLUMNS($A2:A2))),"")`

when data runs out you get blanks

To confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER put formula in A2, press F2 key to select formula then hold down CTRL and SHIFT keys and press ENTER. Curly braces like { and } will appear around the formula in the formula bar - do that before you copy across

Comment: Thanks Barry, that is perfect.  I knew it was an array formula, but the use of iferror was great.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to do this once, this method should work.  If you need to do it by automation, this will need some modification:

1. Make a new column called **ListAllCols** (or whatever).  Use this formula.

   =IF(E2<>"",","&E$1,"")
   & IF(F2<>"",","&F$1,"")
   & IF(G2<>"",","&G$1,"")
   & IF(H2<>"",","&H$1,"")

   Using your example, the first row should return "Column M, Column O, Column R"
2. Select this column, then Copy & Paste Values to get rid of the equations.
3. Using Excel 2007's **Text to Columns** feature (Data->Data Tools->Text to Columns), split this out into 3 separate columns by specifying the comma as the delimiter.